# How do i get the name of all the elastic pools i have in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-elasticpool

I am trying to get the name of the elastic pools I have in a SQL Server on Azure. The problem I am currently facing is that the only way i can get the name of all the Elastic Pools in my SQL Server is by writing

```
var elasticPool = azure.SqlServers.ElasticPools.GetBySqlServer(sqlServer, elasticPoolName);
elasticPool.Name;
```

Here i only get one elastic pool, and to get it, I need to specify the name of the elastic pool that I am trying to get which is kinda sub optimal.

So my question is, is it possible to get the name of all the Elastic Pools in my SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is it possible to get the name of all the Elastic
>   Pools in my SQL Server?

You should be able to get it.

I have not tried it myself but [`ISqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.fluent.isqlserver?view=azure-dotnet) interface exposes a property called [`ElasticPools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.fluent.isqlserver.elasticpools?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_Fluent_ISqlServer_ElasticPools) and that has a [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.fluent.sqlchildrenoperations.sqlchildrenactionsdefinition.isqlchildrenactionsdefinition-1.list?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Sql_Fluent_SqlChildrenOperations_SqlChildrenActionsDefinition_ISqlChildrenActionsDefinition_1_List) operation which should give you the list of elastic pools in a SQL Server.

I found some relevant code here, that you may find useful: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sql-database-dotnet-manage-sql-dbs-in-elastic-pool/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar! Thank you very much. I don't know how i missed that.